# How to get Visual Studio to highlight the corresponding loop for a break statement?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If you have a loop and type `break`, Visual Studio will highlight the keyword and the corresponding loop like so:

[image]

When I end the line with a semicolon and navigate off the line, the highlighting goes away. If I move the cursor:

- Before the `break` statement
- After the `break` statement
- Or anywhere in between

It does not re-highlight the statement it's breaking out of. I have to delete the word and re-type it in order to see this highlighting.

Generally, this isn't a *huge* issue but I've inherited some code which has far more nested loops and `if` statements than any sane programmer should do, so it'd be nice if I could reliably re-apply this formatting without having to re-type the word.

So basically I want it to behave the same way when you position the cursor just before a <kbd>{</kbd> or after a <kbd>}</kbd>. When you do that, it automatically highlights the matching braces.

Is there some setting for this, or perhaps even a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Resharper does all sorts of highlighting. I have it and it does the highlighting you mentioned - click on "break" and it highlights the "for". It also [highlights matching braces](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Matching_Delimiters.html). Resharper is not free, though. Personally, I think it is easily worth the price.

Also look at Viasfora for braces highlighting, it gives each nesting level a different color. Viasfora is free & works fine with Resharper.